# What is the name / Part Number for PCIE 6+2 Power Connectors (Specifically the +2 connector without a retention clip)

Tags: power, connector, identification, pcie

This is the part I'm trying to find:

[image: photo of unknown connectors]

I can find the 6 pin connector (I think), but I can't seem to find the +2 pin connector. I'm attempting to make some cable assemblies for a weird but fun project and need to find a way to get these parts.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Depending on what wire length you need, you might find it easier to just get a ready-made pairs in the form of a [PCI-e power splitter](pci-e power splitter).

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#Form_factors), these are a variant of Molex Mini-Fit Jr. connectors. I searched [here](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/result?s=N4IgTCBcDaILYEsB2CC0AzBAXABAKwCcQBdAXyA) and [here](https://www.mouser.ch/Search/Refine?Keyword=mini-fit%20jr) and have found some with 2 pins. Not sure if they are exactly the same but maybe it helps.